# why there is inconsistency between cherry-pick and merge when there is a conflict

Tags: git

For a standard merge conflict, we resolve the conflict and then use:

```
git add .
git commit
```

but for cherry-pick conflict, we resolve the conflict and then use:

```
git add .
git cherry-pick --continue
```

isn't that a better way to unify them as:

```
// for merge
git add .
git merge --continue
```

or:

```
//for cherry-pick 
git add .
git commit
```

Comment: There actually *is* a `git merge --continue`. It's pretty reasonable to use it. All it does is verify that there is an ongoing merge to finish and then run `git commit`, but that verification step is useful.

Comment: The `--continue` option to `git merge` did not exist in ancient versions of Git, and if you have a sufficiently old one, you won't have it either. As someone who started with an ancient version, I'm still in the habit of using `git commit` instead of `git merge --continue` myself.

Comment: Rebase, revert and cherry-pick provide the `--continue` option. Unlike @torek I am not used to wrapping up my merges with commit... I find it particularly dangerous if there's stuff that's pending to be added.

Answer (score 3):

There are special `--continue` commands for rebase and cherry-pick because you can rebase or cherry-pick multiple commits.  You want to not only resolve the conflict for the current commit, but continue the operation that was in progress after the fact.

For merge, there's no need for this, so the standard tools suffice.  You're not continuing the merge as an ongoing operation; you're just completing it with a single commit.